# What does I1, I2, U1, means in Visio database relationship diagram?

Tags: database, uml, visio

I am reverse engineering an database to create an database ER diagram in Visio.  When I display the table in Visio, on the left hand side of the entity diagram, I see symbols next to the column names that I do not know what they mean.  Symbols such as, U1, U2, l1, l2, l5...etc.  Others symbols such as PK (primary key) and FK (foreign key) are also shown in the same area, but those obviously make sense to me.

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out.  These symbols are names of indices associated with the columns in the tables.

Answer (score 13):

These are other types of indexes.

U1 = Unique Index 1.....
I1 = Index 1......

Here are examples in SQL Server
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx